# Azure Devops. - Importing from one project/repository to another

Tags: azure, repository

I am trying to import project from one repository to another on Azure DevOps and running into this error:

Your import of https://asbc@dev.azure.com/application/repo/_git/mycode repository failed due to VS403655: The push was rejected because storage:621b7803-367a-307b-8a15-0164783333e2 contains ':', which isn't a valid file or directory character. .

All solutions I found are suggesting force push to the new repo but we need to retain history. I will appreciate if there is any way to copy these files without using third-party tools or custom development using APIs.